# Amount of cores per SM and threads per block in CUDA

Tags: cuda

As NVIDIA GPU evolve the amount of cores per SM changes: in Fermi we have 32 of them, but in Maxwell the number is 128 according to the white papers. So, my questions are following:

- Is that better to create grids with blocks, containing 128 threads each? Will such code run faster?
- Does the term "warp" remain the same, 32 threads?
- In a presentation called "CUDA overview" by Cliff Woolley I read that each Fermi SM posses 2 warp schedulers which are able to maintain "up to 1536 threads concurrently". How is that possible given that we have 32 cores? He means that up 48 blocks 32 thread each can wait in queue in order to occupy the cores, so its 32*48 = 1536?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is that better to create grids with blocks, containing 128 threads each? Will such code run faster?

Optimal block size depends on the problem. It's a idea for your block size to be a multiple of the warp size. Other factors are occupancy considerations, and shared memory usage.

> Does the term "warp" remain the same, 32 threads?

So far every architecture specified by NVIDIA has a warp size of 32 threads, though this isn't guaranteed by the programming model.

> In a presentation called "CUDA overview" by Cliff Woolley I read that each Fermi SM posses 2 warp schedulers which are able to maintain "up to 1536 threads concurrently". How is that possible given that we have 32 cores? He means that up 48 blocks 32 thread each can wait in queue in order to occupy the cores, so its 32*48 = 1536?

GPUs work through over-subscription. They require more than one thread per core to operate efficiently. The GPU can switch between threads with zero overhead, so by over-subscribing cores you can keep the core busy by issuing an instruction from a different thread to the same core on the next clock cycle.